# Electrical conversions

Tags: abreviaturas

I am converting from English to Spanish in an electrical program.  It appears that the following abbreviations are the same in Spanish.  Am I correct?

- Voltage = V
- Ampere = A
- Hertz = Hz
- kilo-volt-ampere - kVa
- kilowatt - kW
- Kilovolt-Ampere Reactive - kVar
- Kilopascals - kPa

Answer (score 7):

To be precise, those are not abbreviations, but symbols. That's the reason why they don't end with a dot. And the symbols for all physical magnitudes are international.

As YoMismo says, you have `kVA` and `kVAr` wrong; but, other than that, everything is correct.

Answer (score 4):

If capital letters matter then kVa should be kVA and kVar should be kVAr. The rest seem correct to me.

Comment: Thank you!  I agree with your capitalization comment.  I am sending around 200 lines to a Spanish translator and just verifying that these were correct helps cut down my list.